# socialengine event for send message

Tags: event-handling, messagebox, sendmessage, socialengine

I am making module for SocialEngine 4.8.9. Basically I am buildin chat module and I want to sync SocialEngine message with my chat box. So I need an event that is called after sending message so that I can insert into my table.
Or is there any event that is called after inserting values into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SocialEngine has many hooks and you can attach your operations to these hooks. One of these hooks is **onItemCreateAfter**. This event will be called when a model item is created in the database.

If you check the Messages module's manifest file you'll see the messages module have 2 model **items** named **messages_message** and **messages_conversation** so you can use the **onItemCreateAfter** hook to attach your operations when any of these 2 items are created.

For this example let's say you have created a module via SocialEngine's SDK and your module name is **mymodule**. You can begin using the hook in 2 steps:

1. Attaching your operations to the **onItemCreateAfter** hook in your module's manifest file. You can check manifest files from other modules to get an idea how you should write the following code in the manifest array.

File : **application/modules/Mymodule/settings/manifest.php**

```
'hooks' => array(
  array(
    'event' => 'onItemCreateAfter',
    'resource' => 'Mymodule_Plugin_Core',
  ),
),
```

2. Create the plugin file that will be called by the hook. in the following code **$payload** object will contains the message item.

File : **application/modules/Mymodule/Plugin/Core.php**

```
class Mymodule_Plugin_Core
{
  public function onItemCreateAfter($event)
  {
    $payload = $event->getPayload();

    if( $payload instanceof Core_Model_Item_Abstract ) {

      //Your code here 

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @SohailAnsari You're welcome :) Could you upvote the answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default hook for composing message.You can create new custom hook for the messages and can call that hook when everytime message is send.

Example:http://social-engine-tutorials.blogspot.in/2012/03/social-engine-4-hook-example.html